# Is it ok to rename webm (audio-only) files to .opus?

Tags: audio, file-format, webm, youtube-dl

For `.webm` files obtained with [`youtube-dl`](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) `-f bestaudio` containing no video stream, is it preferable to run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vn -c:a copy output.opus
```

Or can one simply rename the source file, changing the extension?

I mean, the audio stream is clearly the same, but regarding the metadata, is there any downside with the second approach?

---

**Update**: I checked metadata with [`mediainfo`](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo). Even if I save the ffmpeg output to .webm (by running `ffmpeg -i input.webm -vn -c:a copy output.webm`), the metadata differs.

Notice the new entry called "Bit depth":

[image: comparison webm input and webm output with mediainfo GUI]

And for the record, this is the `.opus` result:

[image: opus output of mediainfo GUI]

I'd like a canonical answer on whether there's something in the container definition that identifies it as a "pure audio" file as opposed to an audio/video file, something that is handled correctly only by "re-wrapping" the stream in a *new* container file.

Comment: Suggestion: You can answer this question yourself by using MediaInfo or with a no-op command (`ffmpeg -i input.webm` vs `ffmpeg -i output.opus`). Have you tried this?

Comment: @oldmud0 I had tried mediainfo, but not the second suggestion. I updated the question to address your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) is a subset of [Matroska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska), which is a [container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_(digital)) for multimedia data. [Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)) is an audio format (an audio codec), which is usually stored inside an [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg) container, but can also be stored inside a Matroska container or a WebM container.

When an Opus audio track is stored in an Ogg container, the file name suffix is usually '.opus' (but when a [Vorbis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) audio track is stored in an Ogg file, the suffix is usually '.ogg')

If you change the file name suffix (from '.webm' to '.opus'), the data inside the file will stay the same.

What I usually do to extract the audio track from a webm file is:

```
mkvextract file/path.webm tracks 0:file/path.opus
```

Note that 'file/path.opus' will be an Ogg container with Opus format (if that's what the WebM contained).

mkvextract can be obtained by installing package 'mkvtoolnix-cli' in ArchLinux, for instance.

Comment: I might have an old version of mkvextract, but I had to change the order of the arguments for it to work:
mkvextract tracks file/path.webm 0:file/path.opus

Comment: Thanks. Is using mkvextract instead of ffmpeg just a matter of preference in this case?

Comment: Can "naked" opus audio track exist as files as well? Or is it always embedded in a container format? If I extract an opus "something" from a WebM file, is it an opus track or an Ogg file?

Answer (score 1):

.opus is Opus within an Ogg container ([reference](https://wiki.xiph.org/index.php/MIME_Types_and_File_Extensions) and [RFC 5334](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5334)), .webm is a Matroska container (and it should use a subset of [web-approved codecs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#webm)).  You can also use .mka for a Matroska container with just audio tracks ([reference](https://matroska.org/faq.html#q-what-file-extensions-does-matroska-use)).

Renaming the file is incorrect, the container won't match the extension.  You are able to convert from one container to the other without loss, for example using yt-dlp's remux options.

Comment: Correct. Thank you for the references. Personally, as I'm used to ffmpeg, that's the tool I normally use to extract audio from `.webm` files into my format of choice.